# How to use DaoImpl functions with DSLContext JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, thread-safety, jooq

we noticed randomly dropping database connections (postgres) in our software. Searching through the Jooq documentation, I found that every call of set() methods after initialization may remove thread-safety of the whole framework.

Therefore, my approach is to refactor every method in our BaseDAO getting rid of setConfiguration() function and changing to a DSLContext.

E.g.

```
public TransactionalCallable<Optional<T>> get(I id) {
        return cfg -> {
            try {
                base.setConfiguration(cfg);
                return doGet(id).map(p -> Optional.of(from(p))).orElse(Optional.empty());
            } finally {
                base.setConfiguration(null);
            }
        };
    }
```

```
protected Optional<E> doGet(I id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(base.findById(id));
    }
```

`base` is an instance of DaoImpl.

So how would I implement `base.findById(id)` using a DSLContext?
Did I understand something wrong regarding thread-safety?

Edit: I started with something like this

```
   public TransactionalCallable<Optional<T>> get(I id) {
        return cfg -> doGet(id).run(cfg).map(p -> Optional.of(from(p))).orElse(Optional.empty());

    }

    protected TransactionalCallable<Optional<E>> doGet(I id) {
        return cfg -> {
            try (DSLContext context = using(cfg)) {
                return Optional.ofNullable(base.findById(id));
            }
        };
    }
```

But still not sure how to use that context correctly.

Comment: Why do you set configurations at all? Ideally you would set up your configuration and daos only once and never tamper with configuration state again... From your question, it's not clear what you did wrong *specifically*, but it does seem you're doing a few unnecessary things, including e.g. wrapping `DSLContext` in `try-with-resources`, which doesn't do anything in your case...

Comment: Mainly because each tenant has its own database with a different configuration. Also, because the system can spawn new tenants on the fly. I thought of different approaches like having a DAO instance for each tenant, holding its own configuration. Nonetheless, my hoped was to do it somehow with the DSLContext. I know that the try-with part is not necessary. That was my approach on how I thought I could use the context to execute the findbyid() function using that context. I strongly agree, the best way would be to not to temper with the state.. maybe I have to find a way to do this eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I suspect is leading to your observed side effects, which I can spot in your code here:

```java
public TransactionalCallable<Optional<T>> get(I id) {
    return cfg -> {
        try {
            base.setConfiguration(cfg);
            return doGet(id).map(p -> Optional.of(from(p))).orElse(Optional.empty());
        } finally {
            base.setConfiguration(null);
        }
    };
}
```

... is that you're doing something once per transaction, which should be done only once per tenant: setting the configuration in some context.

It's a lifecycle problem. You seem to be sharing a resource (`base`) across transactions. If this is a shared resource, then it must not be modified per transaction. It should be possible for this `base` to have a lifecycle that corresponds to the tenant lifecycle, or even the application lifecycle, and thus never having to worry about setting this resource again.